# Click Counter in a Customized way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clicks = 0;
    function onClick() {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    };
    </script>
<td><button type="button" onclick="onClick()" >0.1</td>
 <p>Ball Count: <a id="clicks">0.0</a></p>
```

Hi I am trying to create customized click counter, when every 6th click it should go to the next whole number( Example: 0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,1.0 (6th click),1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,2.0(12th click) like wise) and how to decrease the same way... Kindly help me.....

Comment: kindly solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement have some similarities to the time calculation. You can use the following.

## **jQuery version**

```js
var clicks = 0;
$('#plusClick, #minusClick').on('click', function () {
    if( this.id == 'plusClick' )
        clicks += 10;
    else if( clicks > 0 )
        clicks -= 10;
    var first = Math.floor((clicks) / 60);
    var second = clicks - (first * 60);
    if (first < 10) {first = "0" + first;}
    if (second < 10) {second = "0" + second;}
    var value    = first + '.' + second;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = parseFloat(value).toFixed(1);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clicks">0.0</div>
<button id="minusClick">-</button>
<button id="plusClick">+</button>
```

## **JS version**

```js
var clicks = 0;
function onClick(operation) {
    if( operation ){
        clicks += 10;
    } else if(clicks > 0){
        clicks -= 10;
    }
    var first = Math.floor((clicks) / 60);
    var second = clicks - (first * 60);
    if (first < 10) {first = "0" + first;}
    if (second < 10) {second = "0" + second;}
    var value    = first + '.' + second;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = parseFloat(value).toFixed(1);
}
```

```html
<div id="clicks">0.0</div>
<button id="minusClick" onclick="onClick(false)">-</button>
<button id="plusClick" onclick="onClick(true)">+</button>
```

Comment: Hi Rejith thanks for your reply i got what i wanted,but  i want only 0.2 like this( not like this 00.20) .can you help me out??

Answer (score 1):

May be you are looking for something like this:

```
var a = 0;
function increase() {
  if (a % 10 == 5)
    a += 5;
  else
    a++;
  return a / 10;
}
function decrease() {
  if (a % 10 == 0)
    a -= 5;
  else
    a--;
  return a / 10;
}
```

Note that I have used a Global Variable for this, which is not recommended.

**Snippet, without global values.**

```js
var counter = {
  currentValue: 0
};
function increase() {
  var a = counter.currentValue;
  if (a % 10 == 5)
    a += 5;
  else
    a++;
  counter.currentValue = a;
  return a / 10;
}
function decrease() {
  var a = counter.currentValue;
  if (a % 10 == 0)
    a -= 5;
  else
    a--;
  counter.currentValue = a;
  return a / 10;
}
```

```css
input {border: 1px solid #999; padding: 5px; width: 15px; height: 15px; text-align: center; font-family: 'Segoe UI'; line-height: 1; width: 50px;}
input[type=button] {padding: 0; vertical-align: top; width: 35px; height: 27px;}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="-" onclick="currentCount.value = decrease();" />
<input type="text" id="currentCount" value="0" />
<input type="button" value="+" onclick="currentCount.value = increase();" />
```

Comment: can you please give me answer without global variables

Comment: @Prince Added a snippet without global values.

Comment: Thanks @Praveen kumar ,i need one more help,if i added 2 radio button,when i select 1st radio btn it should add value in exixting place,if i click radio button2 it should add value in new place.How can i do this??? Kindly help me on this...

Answer (score 0):

Just change onclick() with

```
function onClick(){
    clicks += 1;
    var a = Math.floor(clicks/6);
    var b = (clicks%6);
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = a + '.' + b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make use of mathematics not some school boy logic,

```
function increment(val) {
    ++val;
    $("button").data("count", val);
    return (val + (Math.floor((val / 6)) * 4)) / 10;
}

$("button").click(function () {
    $('input').val(increment(parseFloat($(this).data("count"))));
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8v1eeLcs/)

Comment: Hi da... `:)` Nice to meet you too! `:)` I am one of the top users last week. Just because I had to search for a job, my rating gone down.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Not an issue. Keep contributing more. What's your location?